# Point example.com/* to website.com/*

Tags: url, cname

How can I point/forward/alias all requests from example.com to website.com such as

example.com/test -> website.com/test

example.com/test2/test -> website.com/test2/test

keeping example.com/test in the address bar, while actually accessing website.com/test.

I own both example.com and website.com but they are not on the same webserver.

website.com has an nginx webserver under CloudFlare, but example.com can be any server.

What are the generic steps to take regardless of the server type?

Comment: That depends on what webserver you are using.

Comment: What are the generic steps to take?
My server (website.com) is nginx, hosted on Amazon, DNS served by CloudFlare. Example.com could be any.

Comment: Configure your webserver to server both domains from the same Virtualhost (in Apache you would use ServerName + ServerAlias).

Comment: The two domains are not on the same webserver.

Comment: You should add that information to your question. It sounds like you want to do proxying, now.